# Listview becomes empty after giving the keyword in search bar in android

Tags: java, android, listview, search, adapter

Currently i'm working on How to find the items from the listview when given the keyword for the item in edittext, the listview becomes empty and the output is displaying in toast message, can anybody help like how to make the found "item" to display it in listivew?

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {

//how many to load on reaching the bottom
    int itemsPerPage = 15;
    boolean loadingMore = false;                        

ArrayList<String> songsList; 
ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter, adapter1;
JSONArray posts;
     //ArrayList thats going to hold the search results
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchResults;
  LayoutInflater inflater;
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://abc.net/ads/?json=get_recent_posts";

 static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
 static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";
private static final String DEBUGTAG = null;
protected static final String TAG = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
    final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //get the LayoutInflater for inflating the customomView
     //this will be used in the custom adapter
     inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);




 final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
                final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url = null;
                    String slug = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);

                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }


              //searchResults=OriginalValues initially
                searchResults=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(songsList);

                      // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
             adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
             list.setAdapter(adapter);

             searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                     //get the text in the EditText
                     String searchString = searchBox.getText().toString();
                     int textLength = searchString.length();

                      //clear the initial data set
                     searchResults.clear();

                     for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
                         String playerName = songsList.get(i).get("title").toString();

                         if (textLength <= playerName.length()) {

                             //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList
                             if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName.substring(0, textLength)))

                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), playerName, 1).show();
                             Home.this.adapter.getFilter();
                             searchResults.add(songsList.get(i));

                            Log.d(TAG, "title");
                         }
                     }

                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                     (Home.this,
                     R.layout.activity_home));
                 }

                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                               int after) {


                 }

                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                     Home.this.adapter.getFilter();

                 }
             });
```

Comment: do you save your item in sqlite database ?

Comment: use ListAdapter filter instead  of Using your custom filter

Comment: Currently m using Lazy Adapter, it seems that some of the adapter doesnt implements the filter interface, is that true?@KapilVats

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Home.this, R.layout.activity_home));
```

You are not giving any data set to populate the `ListView`.

Just like you initially populated the ListView with songsList data

```
adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

use:

```
adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, searchResults);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i already gave this code but getting error in that line as "The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Home, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>, int) is undefined"

Comment: Hmm. That depends on how you defined your constructor. What i mean to say is, use the current data set ie., `searchResults` to populate the `ListView` like you did with `songsList` initially. Check the edited answer

Comment: but still getting error in this line adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, searchResults); as "The constructor LazyAdapter(new TextWatcher(){}, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined" i have defined the constructor as same to songslist,since m new to android i hv tried in all ways pls help me no... @Archie.bpgc

Comment: Thats because of the Context problem. Instead of `this` use `Home.this`.

Comment: I am just trying to tell you where you are going wrong. But the way you implement the search is not recommended. Check the links provided by **@Manish Android**

Comment: thanks for the replies error cleared but no improvement in listview m getting the output.@Archie.bpgc

Answer (score 0):

try this,
edittext code for search

```
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
        adapter1.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    }
  ........
```

add arraylist to listview to display

```
adapter1 = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, mProductArrayList);
lvProducts.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Adapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<Product> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
private ArrayList<Product> mDisplayedValues;    // Values to be displayed
LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> mProductArrayList) {
this.mOriginalValues = mProductArrayList;
this.mDisplayedValues = mProductArrayList;
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
 ..........
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder holder = null;

if (convertView == null) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    holder.llContainer = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer1);
    holder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    holder.tvPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder.tvName.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).name);
holder.tvPrice.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).price+"");

holder.llContainer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mDisplayedValues.get(position).price.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

return convertView;
```

}

Comment: but in my code m using lazyadapter this is not implementing filter interface @saran